# Encryption and decryption with PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to implement encryption and decryption functions in PHP but it is not just working right. Here is the algorithm:

- Encryption key is a master code: `1234567890`.
- Encryption alphabet is `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, =`
- Encrypt each symbol after the signature that belongs to the encryption alphabet. Skip the others.
- Symbol is encrypted by a shift (to the right) in the encrypted alphabet. The shift amount is given by the current digit of the encryption key. The current digit of the encryption key is shifted to the right after each usage and cycled from the end to beginning.

Here is my current code:

```
    function tnsencrypt($master_code,$text) { //the text to be encrypted $plain_text= $text;

//letters of alphabet array $alphabet=array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','=','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

//$alphabet_len = count($alphabet); //$signature_len = 17; // signature=TnpMsgE //$master_code_len = 10; $mcursor = 0;

//positions of the letters in alphabet : The array_flip() function returns an array with all the original keys as values, and all original values as keys. $flip=array_flip($alphabet); //plaintext array $plain_text=str_split($plain_text); $master_code=str_split($master_code);

$n=count($plain_text); $encrypted_text=''; for ($i=0; $i }

}

//echo $encrypted_text; return $encrypted_text; }

function tnsdecrypt($master_code,$text) { //the text to be decrypted $encrypted_text= $text;

//letters of alphabet array $alphabet=array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','=','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'); //positions of the letters in alphabet : The array_flip() function returns an array with all the original keys as values, and all original values as keys. $flip=array_flip($alphabet);

//plaintext array $encrypted_text=str_split($encrypted_text); $master_code=str_split($master_code);

$n=count($encrypted_text); $decrypted_text=''; for ($i=0; $i

} else {
    $decrypted_text.= $encrypted_text[$i];  
}
//move mcursor
$mcursor = ($mcursor+1)%10;
}

//echo $encrypted_text; return $decrypted_text;

}

if(isset($_POST["text"])) { $text = $_POST["text"]; $shifttext = $_POST["shifttext"]; echo "
Encrypted Text: ".tnsencrypt($shifttext,$text); echo "
Decrypted Text: ".tnsdecrypt($shifttext,tnsencrypt($shifttext,$text));

}

?>
```

Here is my result:

Original text: `val1=1234567 val2=abcdef val3=ABCDEF`

Encrypted text: `vjt8F666666F 3hr7Dddddnn 2gq7CCCCMMM`

Encrypted Text: `vjt8F666666F hr7Dddddnn gq7CCCCMMM`

Decrypted Text: `val1=1234567 al2=abcdef al3=ABCDEF`

As you can see, a couple of characters are missing on the encryption and that affected the decryption as well. The missing ones are v on line 2 and v on line 3

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this for fun or for real?  That encrypted output looks far from random as it should.

Comment: If it is for learning / fun, then go ahead. If it is for production use, you should most certainly NOT be using your own encryption algorithm. Use of of the many existing algorithms that have been battle-tested.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? There are several one- and two-way encryption solutions you could be using instead, if this is for actual use and not just an academic exercise:

**One-Way**: [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
**Two-Way**: [`mcrypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Encryption is pretty much a solved problem.